# In rails, does a method called in the before filter of a controller run for every action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say in my rails controller I have a method `set_one()` that will  be called via a `before_filter`. Does this method get called every single time right before a controller action or is it a one time thing that runs throughout the controller? If it's a onetime thing, then that would mean the instance variables it creates would be available throughout the controller. I thought controller actions are stateless. Does this help bridge the gap if it only gets run once before all actions?

```
def set_one
 # do really complex processing and set the variable @one. 
 @one = 1;
end
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: a `before_filter` method is ran once **every request** meaning that if you go to the index action twice, the method is ran once for each of those request.

Comment: oh so if i have some really heavy processing in the before action, there will be slowness, since it will basically run for every single request?!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`before_filter` will call the method for every request to the controller. You can set it to run only for some actions:

```
before_filter :authorize, :only => :delete
```

Or even prevent it from running in particular actions:

```
before_filter :authorize, :except => [:index, :show]
```

BTW, the new syntax for `before_filter` is [`before_action`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_action)